# is there a function to add a unique id to all users in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database (Firebase - Cloud Firestore) with the following structure.

```
users
     |
     unique id (list of unique ids for each user)
```

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhvwI.png)

I would like to assign each user a new field with another unique id that would be used to identify the user. The problem is I don't know-how.

Here are the current fields of each user.
[current fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwcDG.png)

I've tried to make a function in javascript that would allow me to do it using the Firebase API but to no avail.

```js
async function updateAllUsers(){
   firebase.firestore().collection("users").get()
   .then((users) => {
     users.forEach((user) => {
       writeUserData(user.id)
      // console.log(user.id)
     })
   })
  
}

async function writeUserData(uid){
  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
  const snapShot = await userRef.get();
  console.log(uid) --> we get here
  console.log(snapShot.exists) --> we get here, prints true
  if(snapShot.exits){ --> we do not get here
    const userId = uid
    console.log("true if"); --> we do not get here
    try {
      console.log("we updated the id"); --> we do not get here
      await userRef.update({
        userId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error updating user id", error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the console log of the above function working.
[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5La.png)

Any help or point to a direction would certainly help.

Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) that I've looked over but can't seem to find a solution or a point to a good direction.

**edit**

Typo in code found by @Renaud Tarnec
should be snapShot.exists not snapShot.exits

Comment: "`if(snapShot.exits)` --> we do not get here" => there is a typo, it should be `exists`.

Comment: Hello, have you resolved the issue by correcting the typo?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo in the code @Denis T.